# NGINX microcache

Tags: nginx, drupal-7

I'm using D7 with perusio's config, so far so good.
What I want to understand is how microchache works internally and what is the meaning of the configuration parameters in this line:

> fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/microcache levels=1:2
>   keys_zone=microcache:5M max_size=1G inactive=2h
>   loader_threshold=2592000000 loader_sleep=1 loader_files=100000;

I don't know, for example, if max_size=1G (which I assume is the max-size of entire cache) refers to 1G in RAM, and could be a problem if my VPS only has 1G RAM.

loader_files? Maybe the files that could be cached?
loader_sleep? Is it one second for microcaching? That sounds logical but in testing microcaches max time is about 15 seconds.

... And the other parameters I have no idea. Please help me to understand this line.
Thanks.

Comment: You can find more information about that directive [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_path). It's a bit tough to follow if you're new to how the microcache works, like me, but from what I understand, Nginx is only keeping the *keys* of the cached data in memory, and the actual *values* are in the datafiles in the filesystem, which are written to the path in the first parameter, `/var/cache/nginx/microcache`. `max_size`refers to the size of the data on disk, not in memory. But I might be wrong - hence why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link Garret. I'll try to understand it :)